# Binary search and return list from a 2D list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, binary-search

I am new to Python programming and I've been trying this question for a long time but I wasn't able to come up with a solution. The question is that I'm given a list of employee IDs and the birth year of the employees and that I'm supposed to return a list of employee IDs that was born in the input year. The following is an example of the list.

`lst = [[2, 1987], [4, 1990], [6, 1992]...]`

Linear searching requires too much time as there are 1 million employees on the list. Therefore, I think the question requires us to use a binary search. I am supposed to come up with a function that takes the input year and lst to come up with a list that returns the employee IDs. If there are no employees born in the year, it should return an empty list. The following is an example of the function.

input > `get_IDs(2012)`

output > `[102, 204, 199632, 199649]`

I understand that there's inbuilt bisect function which I was able to do for 1D arrays but I'm not sure how to do a binary search for 2D arrays. Please advice on what I should do and any suggestions are largely appreciated!

Comment: You can use the build-in filter function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For binary search to work, you must have a sorted list. Sorting comes at a cost; it represents a *O(nlogn)* time complexity.

However, this can be done without binary search, with linear time complexity, if you use a dictionary, keyed by year:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

# preprocessing
dic = defaultdict(list) # silently create an empty list when addressing a year the first time
for id, year in lst:
    dic[year].append(id)

# implementation of the required function 
def get_IDs(year):
    return dic[year]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, one million elements is not that much on modern hardware, so using filtering / list could be pretty fast. Let's set up some test data first:

```
import random, bisect, operator
random.seed(0)

years = list(range(1950, 2003))
N = 1_000_000

employees = sorted([(i, random.choice(years)) for i in range(N)],
                  key=operator.itemgetter(1))

target_year = 1980
%timeit emp_1980 = [i for i, y in employees if y == target_year]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 261 ms per loop
# can query 4 years per second
```

You could use the builtin `bisect` with lists instead of scalars, but it will compare the first elements (IDs) by default, instead of years that we want. We can get around that with some preprocessing:

```
import bisect
# all (year, id) pairs sorted by year
year_id_sorted = [[y, i] for i, y in sorted(employees, key=operator.itemgetter(1))]

def ids_from_year(target_y):
  result = list()
  # make use of elementwise list ordering
  i = bisect.bisect_left(year_id_sorted, [target_y, 0])
  for y, ID in year_id_sorted[i:]:
    if y == target_y:
      result.append(ID)
    else:
      break
  return result

%timeit ids_from_year(target_year)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 11.9 ms per loop
# can query 100 years per second
```

This yields a speedup by a factor of 26. Not too bad, but we've incurred some pre-processing cost and had to store a copy of the dataset. Now let's try storing employees in dictionary of the following form: "year => list of employees".

```
from collections import defaultdict
employee_by_year = defaultdict(list)
for i, y in employees:
  employee_by_year[y].append(i)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 361 ms per loop
# pre-processing step is only %40 more expensive than
# a single lookup in the original case.

%timeit employee_by_year[target_year]
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 63.2 ns per loop
# can query 16 million years per second
# other factors will likely limit processing speed
```

I suppose that the optimal implementation depends on how often you plan to run the query. Running it at least twice justifies using a `dict`. If you were using a less "granular" metric (e.g. salary), you could justify using a binary search. If you need to query multiple metrics, e.g. year *and* salary, you run into a memory vs. speed trade-off. Then, the best strategy really depends on your data distribution.